# C - is it possible to switch between two different libraries with the same main?

Tags: c, header, include, libraries, program-entry-point

I'm sorry for my newbie question.
I've two libraries that compute the same thing with different structure (one uses queue, the other one uses queue like two stacks).
Both queue and stacks are implemented with array (it isn't a my own decision and so I can't use different structures).
The main is the same for both libraries without any difference, so if I use the first or second library, the main behaves in the same way.
For this reason both libraries have the same name, but they are located in different folders, so I have to put the main.c in the first or second folder in order to use the first or the second library. 
But this is a very dirty practice.
How can I optimize the import of the libraries (maybe at runtime)?
Thanks for the answers.

I hope that I am clear. 
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What OS are you on?  Also, do the exported functions in the two libraries have the same signature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming from your description, both libraries expose functions with identical signatures (function names, types and parameters).

Most operating systems provide a mechanism selecting and loading dynamic libraries at run time. For example, in Linux, you would use `dlopen` and `dlsym` ([man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) to load a selected library into the process's address space and get a function pointer given the function name. Using this, you can create an executable that allows the user to select the library at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use two functions from two files. Maybe you need to separate the codes with *.h and *.c.

for example:

a.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void A() {
  printf("this is A!");
}
```

a.h

```
void A();
```

b.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void B() {
  printf("this is B!");
}
```

b.h

```
void B();
```

main.c

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int main(void) {
  A();
  B();
  return 0;
}
```